# Notification if there is a post requiring review

Tags: feature-request, review

I always hated going to the review page, only to find nothing required reviewing. It is a time-consuming task going between questions and review.

I was thinking, if there were a notification, or at least a little sign, that a review is required, it would save all us reviewers going back and forth between pages. If there is no notification, you will know that nothing needs review and you will continue with what you are doing. If you see a notification, you know there is a review available and you should go to the review page.

Why is there not a notification?

Comment: There is supposed to be a notification on the menu bar (white number on a brown square) whenever there are at least three tasks (though sometimes it's not quite accurate). Do you not see that from time to time?

Comment: @200_success No, I have never seen it.

Comment: Related from Math.SE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/7006/23353 Basically, the solution proposed is to keep a "review" tab open, and either the user script (from StackApps) or the bookmarklet (included in the linked post) continually updates the title of the review page with the current number of review tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a notification system in place. When 3 items or more are visible in the Review queue, you will see a small, orange icon with a number in it. As in this capture. (I will add another screenshot next time I see items there.

[image: review-queue]

As for making it to where it shows whenever there is even only one item, that would be more of a [feature-request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for Stack Exchange.

You will notice sometimes it will show items, but when you click there are none. That means someone else already reviewed them without skipping.

Comment: The number in the bubble is relatively heavily cached and not even user-specific. There may be discrepancies between it and the actually reviewable number of posts. Consider blaming caching in case you click there and there is no available reviews